# Cannot redeclare class WP_REST_Search_Controller

Tags: wordpress

When I want to add a new post in my WordPress website I get the following error with a new white page message:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class WP_REST_Search_Controller in /home1/alfadhmh/public_html/wp-content/plugins/rest-api-search/lib/class-wp-rest-search-controller.php
```

Does anyone know how to approach this error?

Answer (score 0):

A Fatal error is thrown by plugin **rest-api-search**. If it is made by you change the class name or **extend** class as a child.